# HTML tables with different ID's are receiving sames value form AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, symfony

This problem has driven me crazy!! Here is the situation, I have a callback data from my AJAX post method that I need to pass to different HTML table there will be 7 different tables. I have achieve to receive my data from the controller with the different objects.Earlier today i have made my first table which was working great, but when I want to pass value to different table with different data again from the ajax callback data both the table are receiving the same value even if the ID' are different even if there is no ID on the second one... Honestly this have driven me crazy.

Here is my AJAX post METHOD with the callback data:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
      $('#call_back_btn').click(function() {
            $.post("/app_dev.php/AjaxSearch", {
                  person_name: $('#input_text').val()
                },
                function(data) {

                  objConnectors = data[0];
                  objContacts = data[1];
                  var ParseConnector = JSON.parse(objConnectors);
                  var ParseContacts = JSON.parse(objContacts);
                  var cycles;

                  for (cycles = 0; cycles < ParseConnector.length; cycles++) {
                    $('tbodyCONNECTOR').append('<tr>' + ParseConnector[cycles].id + '</td><td>' + ParseConnector[cycles].n_c + '</td><td>' + ParseConnector[cycles].description + '</td></tr>');
                  }

                  for (cycles = 0; cycles < ParseContacts.length; cycles++) {
                    $('tbodyCONTACT').append('<tr>' + ParseContacts[cycles].id + '</td><td>' + ParseContacts[cycles].n_c + '</td><td>' + ParseContacts[cycles].description + '</td></tr>');
                  }
                }
```

As you can see there appends are different

Here is the HTML :

```
div class="bs-example" data-example-id="panel-without-body-with-table">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Available connectors</div>
        <table id="Connectors">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>12NC</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbodyCONNECTOR">

            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bs-example" data-example-id="panel-without-body-with-table">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Available Contacts</div>
        <table id="Contacts">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>12NC</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbodyCONTACT">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are the two tables. 
The value that I get is always the first value so: ParseConnector
I'll highly appreciate any help!!!

Comment: You are missing the # in your selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('tbodyCONNECTOR').append("...");
```

and

```
$('tbodyCONTACT').append("...");
```

are missing the hash symbol.

Try with `$('#tbodyCONNECTOR').append("...");`

Same goes for `tbodyCONTACT`

Comment: Thanks man, perhaps that what was the most stupid question today :D or its just end of the day and I'm out of caffeine.....

Comment: No question is stupid. And this happens to everyone spending a good chunk of the day staring at the screen. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

As  I can't comment, I just want to point out that after briefly looking at it, shouldn't these lines

```
$('tbodyCONNECTOR').append('<tr>' + ParseConnector[cycles].id + '</td><td>' + ParseConnector[cycles].n_c + '</td><td>' + ParseConnector[cycles].description + '</td></tr>');

$('tbodyCONTACT').append('<tr>' + ParseContacts[cycles].id + '</td><td>' + ParseContacts[cycles].n_c + '</td><td>' + ParseContacts[cycles].description + '</td></tr>');
```

be

```
$('#tbodyCONNECTOR').append('<tr>' + ParseConnector[cycles].id + '</td><td>' + ParseConnector[cycles].n_c + '</td><td>' + ParseConnector[cycles].description + '</td></tr>');
$('#tbodyCONTACT').append('<tr>' + ParseContacts[cycles].id + '</td><td>' + ParseContacts[cycles].n_c + '</td><td>' + ParseContacts[cycles].description + '</td></tr>');
```

I'm sure you just missed this, but these are needed when selecting an element with an ID, when getting one with a class you would use a . instead of a # (think of CSS)

Answer (score 2):

You are - as already mention in the comment - missing the `#` in front of the selector.

Beside that if you want to add the exact same content to both you could use one loop and use this selector `#tbodyCONNECTOR, #tbodyCONTACT`:

```
for (cycles = 0; cycles < ParseConnector.length; cycles++) {
  $('#tbodyCONNECTOR, #tbodyCONTACT').append('<tr>' + ParseConnector[cycles].id + '</td><td>' + ParseConnector[cycles].n_c + '</td><td>' + ParseConnector[cycles].description + '</td></tr>');
}
```

Or add a common class to both `tbody`.

In general you should avoid to query for the same elements over and over again in the loop so it would be better to write it that way:

```
var tbodyElements = $('#tbodyCONNECTOR, #tbodyCONTACT');

for (cycles = 0; cycles < ParseConnector.length; cycles++) {
  tbodyElements.append('<tr>' + ParseConnector[cycles].id + '</td><td>' + ParseConnector[cycles].n_c + '</td><td>' + ParseConnector[cycles].description + '</td></tr>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the use of jQuery [ID Selector ('#id')](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) because you are missing the `#` in the selectors.

Also notice that instead of using selectors pointing to the table's `tbody`:

```
$('#tbodyCONNECTOR')
$('#tbodyCONTACT')
```

You should use [ID Selector ('#id')](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) pointing to the table, and then get the `tbody` element of a table:

```
$('#tableId > tbody')
```

Code:

```
$('#Connectors > tbody')
$('#Contacts > tbody')
```